# Possessive pronoun after sein

Tags: difference, possessive-pronoun

Which is/are correct and why?

1. Der Hund ist mein.
2. Der Hund ist meiner.

My thinking is that only 2 is correct. If a noun follows *mein-?* then it's a determiner, and the masculine possessive determiner is *mein*. (See the inflection table [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mein#Declension).) If a noun does not follow the *mein-?* then it's a pronoun and the masculine possessive pronoun is *meiner*. (See the inflection table [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meiner#Declension).)

On the other hand one grammar I looked at said there is a special uninflected form *mein* used specifically after *sein* or similar verbs. So *dieses Haus ist mein* not *dieses Haus ist meins*. Another grammar I looked at seem to agree with my reasoning. DeepL allows both versions and the DWDS usage database has examples with both variations:

> *Du bist mein.* ("Game of Thrones" The Prince of Winterfell, 2012)
> *Du bist meiner.* (Transformers 3 - Die dunkle Seite des Mondes, 2011)

If either version is a allowed, is there a difference in meaning? If it depends on circumstances, which version is used when?

Comment: Auch: Dein ist mein ganzes Herz.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think `Something is meiner/meine/meins` is normally used. `Du bist mein` is used for a beloved person or maybe also in poetic texts. (I don't write this as an answer because I'm not sure about the rules. I'm a native German.)

Comment: @Bodo: I think you may be onto something and that matches with something I just read in another (perhaps dated) grammar. I'm going to put my current thinking in an answer as a working theory so see if anyone can poke holes in it.

Answer (score 3):

There are various ways you can look at this, I'll simply present mine (sic):

> Ist das dein Hund? Nein, das ist nicht meiner - sondern seiner.

Is a substantival usage of a personal pronoun, so no genitive, even it it looks like one. (Proven by: "Ist das deine Katze, nein, das ist seine")

> Der Hund ist mein

is an adjective usage of the same pronoun, and yes, it's uninflected (only used in masculine singular). (Like "Der Hund ist braun").

Both are valid and OK, but the second form is archaic and only found in old texts or in archaic scenarios like GOT.

> Die Rache ist mein, sagt der Herr

(Compare your favorite King James Edition, Romans 12:19)

> Der Sieg ist unser

Comment: I think I see what you're saying, but I don't think the uninflected form is archaic since I see it in subtitles for TV and movies set in the present day. It appears in "Die Zeit" as well: *Die Situation ist mein, weil sie das Bild der freien Wahl meiner selbst ist; alles, was sie mir darbietet, ist mein insofern, als es mich darstellt und symbolisiert.* (1983, it's a quote but I can't find out from who without going through a paywall.) There does seems to be a slight difference in meaning, but I can't quite put it into words.

Comment: @RDBury That's a Sartre quote you're giving. Existientialism wasn't exactly yesterday ;)

Comment: Well, 20th century. Anyway, didn't Sartre write in French? I looked for other examples from Die Zeit but it looks like most of them are quotations of some kind, but you could say that about the other version. Maybe Die Zeit isn't best place to look for examples.

Comment: @RDBury It's definitely archaic or lyric. No modern German native speaker talks like that. If they do, they allude to a quote.

Answer (score 1):

I did a bit more research in additional grammars and I have a working theory: If you're talking about actual ownership then you'd always use the inflected form, so only *Der Hund ist meiner* is correct assuming you actually own the dog. If it's a more figurative meaning of the possessive then the uninflected form is allowed. So *Du bist mein* (see Bodo's comment above) is possible because you're expressing affection and commitment rather than ownership. (At least I *hope* that's what you're expressing.) If it's an abstract concept that no one can own then the uninflected form is also allowed: "*Die Rache ist mein.*" (See tofro's answer.) *Der Sieg ist mein.* *Der Tag ist mein.* *Die Ehre ist mein.* Also when you're expressing victory or control over something: *Die Stadt ist mein.* *Die Menschen sind mein.* It's a bit tricky since being optional does not imply it's mandatory.

Anyway, this seems to fit the available data, but feel free to poke holes in it.